# Error in do map of array inside html in nodejs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, google-cloud-functions

everybody
i have this peice of code in nodejs

```
<table class="invoice-items" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                        <tbody>
                                       { ${Object.values(services).map((service)=>                                       
                                          <tr key={service.title}>
                                         <td>${service.title}</td>
                                          <td>${service.price}</td>
                                              </tr>
                                        )}}
                                      </tbody>
                                      </table>
```

and get this error
E:\ReactCode\SoapyJoes\soapyjoes_dashboard\functions\index.js:115

```
 <tr key={service.title}>
                                      ^


[
   { price: '35', quantity: '1', title: 'wash&fold', weight: '2' },
   { price: '10', quantity: '3', title: 'wash', weight: '3' }
 ]
```

this is services values
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'

Comment: Why do you have the `$` before your map? That could be causing the syntax issue.

Comment: because it is inside var in node js   html:` <table class="body-wrap">
       
         <tbody>
                                       ${Object.values(services).map((service)=>{
                                        return( 
                                          <tr key={service.price}>
                                         <td>${service.title}</td>

Comment: I don't think that's correct... Try it without. In JSX you just use `{ }` to use JS expressions/variables

Comment: @BrianThompson ok the error is gone but the function of the code does not work

Comment: The next steps would be to include the value of `services` in the question, and I would also wrap the returned JSX from the `map` with `( )` since multiline implicit returns can issues

Comment: [
>    { price: '35', quantity: '1', title: 'wash&fold', weight: '2' },
>    { price: '10', quantity: '3', title: 'wash', weight: '3' }
>  ] this is services

Comment: I'm assuming the `>` are not actually there?? If so, remove the `Object.values` and just do `services.map(` since it already appears to be an array

Comment: yes you right i added the values of services in question

Comment: when I do it without Object.values map is not working because it is object not array

Comment: The value you posted for `services` is an array. So either that is not the actual value of `services` or the variable is changing datatypes during your code's execution.

Comment: {
 '07b74e70-68a4-4f30-acc4-5543d37572d7': { price: '90', quantity: '4', title: 'fold', weight: '8' }
  } this is services

Comment: But you just said [
   { price: '35', quantity: '1', title: 'wash&fold', weight: '2' },
   { price: '10', quantity: '3', title: 'wash', weight: '3' }
 ] this is services.

Comment: Please console.log(services) before mapping services and showing it in table row.

Comment: @PriyashreeBhadra   { '07b74e70-68a4-4f30-acc4-5543d37572d7': { price: '90', quantity: '4', title: 'fold', weight: '8' } } this before mapping

Comment: I have posted an answer with a working code( made little changes to your code). It is working fine for me. Please try and let me know if it worked. I initialised the services object in App.js itself as I do not have other js files. If this code doesn't work for you, then I think the mistake is probably in your other js files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

I reproduced your code, made some changes and it was working fine for me after that. I am attaching the screenshot as well as the code for the same.

**Code implemented :**

```
import React from "react";
export default function App() {
 
 const services =  { '07b74e70-68a4-4f30-acc4-5543d37572d7': { price: '90', quantity: '4', title: 'fold', weight: '8' } }
 
 console.log(Object.entries(services))
 console.log(Object.values(services))
 
 return (
   <div>
 
   {<table style={{border:"1px solid red"}}>
                                       <tbody >
                                      {Object.values(services).map((service)=>
                                      {console.log(services)
                                        return(
                                         <div>
                                        <tr>
                                         <th> Services </th>
                                         </tr>
                                          <tr key={service.title}>
                                        <td>{service.title}</td>
                            
                                        <td>{service.price}</td>
                                       </tr>
                                       </div>
                                         )}                                     
                                      )}
                                   </tbody>
                                   </table> }                           
   </div>
)}
```

I hope this works for you.